# HTML5 Local storage and testing for values not null

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I am storing my shopping cart details in HTML5 local storage as follws:

```
Cart_items{"SCI-1":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-1","price":23.52,"name":" product 1","pid":"5"}}
```

I am testing for a condition such that if there are no items in local storage a dropdown menu is set to disabled as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
if (localStorage.getItem("Cart_items") != null) {

$("#procurselect").attr('disabled','disabled');
$("#procurselect").css('pointer-events','none'); // this makes it unclickable
$("#procurselect").prop( "disabled", true );

}
</script>
```

the issue is that even if i add no items to my cart is is displaying 1 item in local storage in firebug as follows:

```
1 item in Storage Cart_items="{}"
```

Hence my condition is always not NULL....How can i overcome this??

Is my code

```
if (localStorage.getItem("Cart_items") != null)
```

incorrect ?????

**My aim is to check whether there are any values in local storage Cart_items.**

I am using jQuery.

Help requested. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

resolved issue as follows:

```
function isObjectEmpty(object)
{
var isEmpty = false;
for(keys in object)
{
isEmpty = true;
break; // exiting since we found that the object is not empty
}
return isEmpty;
}


var myObject = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("Cart_items") );//object
var isEmpty  = isObjectEmpty(myObject); 
// check if the object is not empty
isEmpty  = isObjectEmpty(myObject); 
if (isEmpty){
//do something
}
```

Thanks for all the help offered...

Comment: Try once with removing `!= null`

Comment: I think it is also treating empty json object {} to be an object, hence saying 1 item in object. So it should work with @Satpal comment above, because check of empty and null are implicitly taken care of.

Comment: @Satpal you should post that as answer.

Comment: @Satpal if (localStorage.getItem("Cart_items")) { not working...dropdown is disabled

Comment: @user3790186 Yes, that's what he meant. "simpleCart_items" was it?

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt The answer by satpal is not working. My dropdown is still disabled even with no items set..

Comment: is the css changed (I mean to know whether the condition was checked true).. and try to replace attr('disabled','disabled) with  .prop( "disabled", true );

Comment: @ nsthethunderbolt Sorry, mistake while typing ..it is Cart_items ...Not working ??

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt Tried prop( "disabled", true ); No change..If i navigate to another page, the dropdown is enabled, even if i add 1 item to storage. If there is an item it should be disabled ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have 1 item in localstorage, which is your empty object.

Change your check to this and it should work.

```
var storedCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Cart_items"));
if ( storedCart != null && Object.keys(storedCart).length>0)
```

Comment: Sorry..it is not working. My dropdown is still disabled evn if no items

Comment: yeah sorry I never de-Stringified it, so it's currently a JSON string not an object, an empty objects as a string is 2 characters length. I'll change answer

Comment: I changed it. Notice the `JSON.parse` on the data from localstorage.

Comment: No change...If there is 1 item in the cart, the dropdwon is "Enabled". It should be disabled if value not null..

Comment: In your original question you say the dropdown is always being disabled as the if is always being hit. Now you say there's been no change and you also say the value is enabled if there if there is 1 value in the cart. It seems to me like you're not making sense/ being consistent. Please clarify.

Comment: OK, the problem is that objects don't have a property length, that was stupid of me. I'll post a fix in a minute.